# Why is python faster than my code in C for calculating factorials of huge numbers?

Tags: python, c, performance, biginteger, factorial

I wrote a program in C that represents a number as an array of 32 bit unsigned integers, in base 2^32-1 in order to calculate the hexadecimal value of the factorial of 100,000.
I wrote the program and tried to optimize it, but it's just way too slow.
It takes about 15 seconds on my laptop, while almost identical C code that uses the GMP library takes only about one second, and code in python, that uses the inbuilt python Big Integer library, but **not** the inbuilt python "math.factorial" function, takes about 3.5 seconds.
I'm surprised by the result because the code I wrote in C seems to be the simplest way it can be done.
I'm aware of more efficient factorial algorithms, but I didn't use them in python or with GMP, and both were still significantly faster than my code.

My code in C in Visual Studio 2019:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MASK_32_UPPER (uint64_t)0x00000000ffffffff
inline void self_multiply(uint32_t* num_array, int32_t* used_length_num_array_ptr, uint32_t num2)
{
    uint64_t carry = 0;
    uint64_t u64num2 = num2;
    int32_t used_length_num_array = *used_length_num_array_ptr;
    int32_t index = 0;
    while (index < used_length_num_array) //iterate through num_array
    {
        carry += num_array[index] * u64num2; //third grade algorithm
        num_array[index] = (uint32_t)(carry & MASK_32_UPPER); //get the 32 insignificant digits
        carry >>= 32; //keep only the 32 significant digits
        index++;
    }
    if (carry != 0) //in this case, num_array will be one digit longer than before
    {
        num_array[index] = carry;
        (*used_length_num_array_ptr) += 1;
    }
}
void print(uint32_t* num_to_print, int32_t length)
{
    int counter = length - 1;
    while (counter >= 0)
    {
        printf("%08x ", num_to_print[counter]);
        counter--;
    }
}
int main()
{
    //....starting the timer......
    clock_t t;
    t = clock();
    //....finished timer initialization.......
    uint32_t *answer = malloc(50000 * sizeof(uint32_t)); //number is in base: 2^32-1
    //uint32_t answer[50000 * sizeof(uint32_t)]; //same perfomance with heap and with stack
    answer[0] = 1;
    int32_t answer_used_length = 1;
    uint32_t counter = 2;
    while (counter <= 100000U) //calculate the factorial of one hundred thousand
    {
        self_multiply(answer, &answer_used_length, counter);
        counter++;
    }
    t = clock() - t;  //measuring time difference between start and end of calculation.
    double time_taken = ((double)t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // in seconds
    print(answer, answer_used_length); //printing result in hexadecimal
    free(answer);
    printf("\n\nlength of answer used in number of uint32_t: %d", answer_used_length);
    printf("\n%f seconds to calculate \n", time_taken);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
00000001 20ccaa20.........
length of answer used in number of uint32_t: 47398
14.643000 seconds to calculate
```

My python code:

```
import datetime
def Factorial(num):
    answer = 1
    numPlusOne = num + 1
    for counter in range(2, numPlusOne):
        answer *= counter
    return answer
startTime = datetime.datetime.now()
answer = Factorial(100000)
timeTook = datetime.datetime.now() - startTime
print("One hundred thousand factorial:\n" + hex(answer))
print("Time took to compute: " + str(timeTook))
```

Output:

```
Squeezed text(3215 lines)
Time took to compute: 0:00:03.434298
```

So my question is: Why? what makes my code in C so slow?

Edit:

My question has nothing to do with the Karatsuba algorithm, because I'm multiplying a 32bit int array and a **single** 32bit integer.
Because of that, my algorithm is O(n), so no need for Karatsuba.

Also, for people who were talking about assembly optimizations, or optimization settings in the compiler, I would like further explanations, because I'm not familiar with most compiler settings.

Comment: If I'm reading your post correctly, you say that your C implementation of bigints is 15x slower than GMP's?  Have you looked into how GMP implements multiplication and how it stores bigints?

Comment: I would look into how Python does multiplication between two `int`s. I suspect Python's BigInt implementation to be orders of magnitude faster than your handmade base 2^32-1 implementation. At least that's the first logical explanation that comes to my mind.

Comment: Try to do the same loop in C - otherwise what you are comparing.

Comment: How did you compile your C code? Is optimization enabled?

Comment: On x86-64, using 64 x 64 => 128-bit math may speed your code up.

Comment: @i486 They did...? 2/3 of the question is the C code.

Comment: Python uses carefully optimized C code plus advanced algorithms (e.g. Karatsuba). GMP has carefully optimized assembler for common CPUs, plus all the advanced algorithms (Karatsuba, FFT). You might try Karatsuba yourself, it is not too difficult.

Comment: Your integers are base 2^32, not base 2^32-1

Comment: @Ronen Create a [release build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/release-builds?view=vs-2019) to enable compiler optimizations. [How to: Create a Release Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-create-a-release-build?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Out of curiosity, tried this with the GCC compiler - C Code 1.67 seconds versus Python 2.69 seconds.